# Repeat the for loop if timeout occured

Tags: c#, loops, watin

I'm using Watin to automate download file from a website. At some point a timeout error occurs if the webserver does not respond in certain time. I would like to know for what index the timeout occurs and for that index to repeat the for loop.

For example:

```
for (int index = 0; index < ros.Count; index++)
{
    //download document
    FileDownloadHandler down = new FileDownloadHandler(dir+nume+"_"+ro+".pdf");
    using (new UseDialogOnce(browser.DialogWatcher, down))
    {
        down.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(100);
        down.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(100);
    }
}
```

When the timeout occurs i want to know for what index in for loop and i would like to retry the download handler. Is it possible ?

Comment: If it is trhowing exception, then you can put try and catch block and on catch exception you can see when it happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the timeout throws an exception. You should figure out which exception exactly is thrown, and then you can catch it inside your loop:

```
for (int index = 0; index < ros.Count; index++) 
{ 
    //download document
    try 
    { 
        FileDownloadHandler down = new FileDownloadHandler(dir+nume+"_"+ro+".pdf"); 
        using (new UseDialogOnce(browser.DialogWatcher, down)) 
        { 
            down.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(100); 
            down.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(100); 
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO: Handle timeout. The value of index will tell you when the timeout occured
    } 
}
```